# Ruby Cipher Error on decrypting something encrypted with Java

Tags: java, ruby, encryption, openssl

I have received the encryption request from a different provider, they were using AES GCM No Padding. When I am trying to decrypt it in ruby getting an error **OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError ()**. I observed in Java the IV is accepting the 16 bytes(Array of Zeros) whereas ruby is limited to 12 bytes only. I am missing something here. Appreciate your help in advance

Code Snippet for Java

```
SecretKey sessionKey = getSessionKey();
byte[] IV = new byte[16];
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(sessionKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(16 * 8, IV);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
responseMap.put("data", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedText));
```

Code snippet for Ruby

```
decrypted_key = "AES KEY"
decode_data = Base64.strict_decode64(params["data"])
cipher_text_with_auth_tag = decode_data.unpack("C*")
auth_tag = cipher_text_with_auth_tag.last(16).pack("C*")
cipher_text = cipher_text_with_auth_tag[0..-17].pack("c*")
decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-GCM')
decipher. decrypt
decipher.padding = 0
decipher.key = decrypted_key
decipher.iv =  "\x00" * 12
decipher.auth_data = ''
decipher.auth_tag = auth_tag
decrypted_data = decipher.update(cipher_text) + decipher.final
```

Comment: For GCM a 12 bytes nonce is recommended, although any size is possible. If the Ruby implementation only allows the recommended 12 bytes, the nonce size must be adjusted on the Java side. Without identical nonce sizes, both codes are incompatible.

Comment: By the way, for GCM no key/IV pairs may be reused. Since a static IV is used, this means that a different key must be used for each encryption.

Comment: @Topaco Sadly, cannot change the nonce in the Java side as it is being handled by the third-party team. And yes for each encryption a new key is generated

Comment: I see another library  **rbnacl** which is again limited to 12 bytes for IV. I have a doubt is the cipher error happened due to Java using 16 bytes(zeros) and Ruby using 12 bytes (zeros) or any other thins that I am missing here.

Comment: According to my test the Ruby code works if a 12 bytes IV is used for encryption. But as long as you use different IVs/IV sizes, the codes are incompatible and decryption will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different IV/nonce length in OpenSSL, but you need to call [`iv_len=`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/exts/openssl/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-iv_len-3D) first.

something like this should work:

```
decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-GCM')
decipher.decrypt
decipher.key = key

# Call iv_len= before iv=
decipher.iv_len = iv_len # e.g. 16 in your case
decipher.iv = iv

decipher.auth_data = ''
decipher.auth_tag = auth_tag

decrypted_data = decipher.update(encrypted_data) + decipher.final()
```